# Multiple @ElementCollection mapped to different columns of the same table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my POJO class, I have 3 related lists with the same length with no null values:

```
List<String> date;
List<String> priceA;
List<String> priceB;
```

Can I map them to 1 table instead of 3, so that I can have a row of (class_id, date, priceA, priceB)?

Comment: No. If you want that structure of table, structure your model to suit. 3 independent lists do NOT map to a single table ... ever. The clue is in the "independent"

Comment: Also, A date and a price shouldn't be stored as strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only if you are willing to change your java model:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "ITEM_DETAIL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
private List<ItemDetail> details;
```

where

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemDetail implements Serializable
{
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column
    private Double priceA;

    @Column
    private Double priceB;

    // getters/setters
}
```